# Saving an image created in MS Word as .eps

Tags: export, file-format, eps, microsoft-word

I have created an image in MS Word using the `Shapes` tools, so on my hands is a `.docx` (or at best `.pdf`) file.  Now I have to have an `.eps` file from the contents. I tried converting the `.pdf` to `.eps` but quality was severely reduced.

Is there any way or software to take this file and save it as `.eps`?

Comment: Do you have any other software? The PDF can be opened in wither Acrobat or Illustrator and then re-saved as an EPS file easily.

Comment: I have GIMP and Inkscape, and Preview for viewing PDF (it's a MacBook), but none give the option of saving as EPS unfortunately.

Comment: So if I manage to find a Windows machine, it needs to have Adobe Illustrator and then it's job done? (the other one you mentioned is simply Adobe Reader is it?)

Comment: Inkscape may open your PDF without an issue. I'd try that first. If it fails, then yes Adobe Illustrator or Adobe Acrobat (not Reader) will both work.

Answer (score 2):

To save an [Encapsulated PostScript (EPS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulated_PostScript) file from a page in your publication, you will need to use a color [PostScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript) printer driver. If you don’t have a color PostScript printer, you can set up the Generic Color PS for Commercial Printing printer driver.

```
Set up the Generic Color PS for Commercial Printing color printer driver.
```

ShowWindows 2000

ShowWindows XP

1. On the File menu, click Print.
2. Under Printer, select Generic Color PS for Commercial Printing.
3. Select Print to file.
4. Click Properties, and then click Advanced.
5. Under printer name Advanced Document Settings, expand Document Options, and then expand PostScript Options.
6. Click next to PostScript Output Option, choose Encapsulated PostScript (EPS) from the drop-down menu, and then click OK twice to return to the Print dialog box.
7. Under Print range, type the range for the single page you want to save as an EPS file. For example, to save page 2 as an EPS file, type “2” in the From box, and then type “2” in the To box.
8. Click Advanced Print Settings.
9. For Output, select Composite CMYK, and then click OK.
10. In the Print dialog box, click OK to print.
11. In the Print to file dialog box, select a location to save the EPS file to, and then type a name for your file. Be sure to use the filename extension .eps.
    Click Save.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping. It's a Mac I'm using, and I did manage to save it as PS but not EPS unfortunately. Any similar procedure for a Mac? Many many thanks,

Comment: Your welcome, and please Don't import EPS-files in Powerpoint for slide show purposes. Use EMF instead. However, if you will print your Powerpoint document as a PDF file or to a Postscript printer you may well use the EPS-format.

Comment: @user4628 http://www.verypdf.com/wordpress/201208/free-to-convert-office-word-to-postscript-ps-and-eps-31397.html

Comment: @user4628 Even if you end up with a .ps, you can always use Adobe Acrobat Distiller to the highest quality print setting, and drag your file on this software. It will create a PDF you can then open with software such as Illustrator. If you're lucky, it will be a nice vector file! Then you can do some clean up and resave it in the format you want.

Answer (score 0):

I know some guy that used [WordToLatex converter](http://www.wordtolatex.com/) for the task described.

I am not using Word anymore, however probably [this tutorial](http://www.wordtolatex.com/blog/converting-microsoft-word-images-to-eps-embedded-in-latex/) will help you to achieve your goals.

Comment: Thanks. System requirements: Windows. I have a Mac, so presumably wouldn't work.

Comment: So you use osX. For me Word is Windows based app, so I thought you are on Win. Update your question, it will help...

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on the image in linux you may get save graphics option. There save format is there. You can select encapsulated postscript. At least in Ubuntu 12.04 I can see this.
Sanjay

Comment: Is there a MS Word for linux/Ubuntu/unix/... available? As far as I know not.  Can you please clarify which image you mean? In `.docx`, `pdf`, ...

Comment: The user is on a MacBook, so this answer isn't too helpful...

Answer (score 0):

Inkscape on a macbook can save as eps. Open whatever image, png, etc., in inkscape, then 'File' --> 'Save As' and the 'save as' window pops up. Click on the box above the 'Save' button and a huge list of output formats comes up. One of them is eps. Been using this for several years now ever since Illustrator went to their monthly licensing scheme. It's not too often that I take an image from ppt or word and convert, but I do recall having issues with image quality. One quick and dirty solution I used as a deadline approached was to use the mac 'Grab' app. I think it comes installed. Grab saves the image as a tiff file, and the quality is surprisingly good. Then import the tiff into Inkscape and save as eps with 300 dpi resolution. Will be good enough for a report or paper.